# i am getting the number of row selected after executing the query not the result?

Tags: php, yii

I am new to yii, while executing the query ,I am getting the numbers of rows selected but not the the actual selected data.

Hows can i get the actual data selected.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT a.CONTENT_ID,a.CONTENT_TITLE 
    FROM TBL_CONTENT_DETAILS a JOIN TBL_CONTENTS b 
    ON a.CONTENT_ID=b.CONTENT_ID 
    WHERE (b.CONTENT_TYPE_ID =22 or b.CONTENT_TYPE_ID=53) 
    and a.CONTENT_ID not in ($notin)";

$connection = Yii::app()->db2;
$command    = $connection->createCommand($sql);
$res        = $command->execute();
```

$notin contains comma separated integer id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$command->queryAll();` instead

`execute()` will always return the number of affected rows, whereas `fetchAll()` will get you an array of results.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand/#queryAll-detail

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you wanted

```
$rows = $command->queryAll(); // query and return all rows of result
```

[Read more about it here.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#fetching-query-results)